# JavaScript: Add delay to a jquery ajax retry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've got code in the following structure. The intent is to send an Ajax request, and to retry it some number of times with a delay between each try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://example.com',
  retryLimit: 3,
  attempt: 1,
  success: function (data) {
    doStuff();
  },
  error: function (data) {
    if (this.attempt++ <= this.retryLimit) {
      var retry = function () {
        $.ajax(this);
      };
      setTimeout(retry, 1000);
    } else {
      handleError();
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that I'm getting a `TypeError: Illegal invocation` when trying to call `$.ajax`.  I also attempted to replace with promises, like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
}).then(function() {
  $.ajax(this);
});
```

But I got the same error.  What is going on, and how can I resolve it?

*NOTE: I'm using the Atlassian SDK to build a Jira plugin, so my javascript version seems to be limited. I'm not 100% sure* which *version I have, but I know it fails to compile when I try to use arrow functions.*

Comment: What is `this` when the retry is attempted?  It sounds like you may need to store it in a variable for the closure.  Something like: `var self = this;  var retry = function () { $.ajax(self); }`

Comment: exactly that - or use an arrow function for `retry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of `this` has changed by the time that `retry()` function executes, and is no longer the AJAX info.  You should, however, be able to wrap it in a closure by using a variable:

```
var self = this;
var retry = function () {
    $.ajax(self);
};
```

(Note that this whole context is itself also happening in a callback, `error`.  So if `this` still isn't what you need it to be, you may need to apply this same concept another scope higher.)

Comment: so [this](https://pastebin.com/dPrRfdwq) worked.  Why did `this` change in the scope of the `retry` function, but _not_ in the scope of the `error` argument?

Comment: @ewok: It's possible to specify the context of `this` when binding a function, jQuery may be doing that for you in the callbacks to `$.ajax()`.